# Center div indifferent monitor?

Tags: html, css

I need help centering a div regardless of monitor size.

I am sending a picture. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: First off, welcome to Stack Overflow. Second, please include what you've tried or you'll be down-voted a lot here. This website is not for asking for code, it's for assisting with problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#myDiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: -400px; /* width divided by 2 */
}
```

This is one simple way to do it. However, making it `position: absolute` might cause some problems if you have other elements around it.

If it has a fixed height, you can put it in a container `div` to which you set that `height` and `position: relative`, so that other elements keep their initial positions, like so:

```
#container{
    position: relative;
    height:500px; /* add this height to #myDiv */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</div>
```